# Cake PHP Drop-down not displayed after submitting the form its displaying

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP I need one help from you guys...!!

I have a controller named ContactusController.php where I have put this associates :

```
$customerStatuses = $this->Contactus->CustomerStatus->find('list');
$enquiryTypes = $this->Contactus->EnquiryType->find('list');
$this->set(compact('customerStatuses', 'enquiryTypes'));
```

and in the ctp file i have this inside form :

```
echo "<div class='control-group'>\n";
        echo "". $this->Form->input('enquiry_type_id', array('type'=>'select', 'label' => 'Type Of Enquiry')) ."\n";
        echo "</div>\n";

        echo "<div class='control-group'>\n";
        echo "". $this->Form->input('customer_status_id', array('type'=>'select', 'label' => 'Customer Type')) ."\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
```

also in model I did the associations like this :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'CustomerStatus' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerStatus',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_status_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'EnquiryType' => array(
        'className' => 'EnquiryType',
        'foreignKey' => 'enquiry_type_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

but I can't see the drop down list of CustomerStatus and EnquiryStatus.When I click the submit button then only it appears.I don't know what the problem I am havine

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you created form in your ctp file ?

Comment: What is your complete controller code? The error most likely can be found there.

Comment: Thanks a lot i just need to paste the code after post method                    $customerStatuses = $this->Contactus->CustomerStatus->find('list');
$enquiryTypes = $this->Contactus->EnquiryType->find('list');
$this->set(compact('customerStatuses', 'enquiryTypes'));

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work....

```
echo $this->Form->input('enquiry_type_id', array(
    'label' => 'enquiry',
    'id' => 'enquiry_id',
    'options' => 'post your array which contains the options'
));
```